# Quota limit in a shared host envirionment

Tags: linux, shared-hosting, inode, disk-space-utilization, centos6.4

people!

I'm studying Linux for taking the LPIC-1 exam. When studying quotas, I was wondering something:

Since you can overflow a disk space creating an infinite number of 0 bytes files, setting a user quota by iNodes would be wise. However, if you imagine an environment of a shared hosting service, I think there isn't any way that you can guess a number of files to limit.

So, how would you avoid someone to exceed the disk's iNode limit? What rule could be applied?

Regards and thank you in advance.

Comment: You seem to be asking what a reasonable inode limit would be, or how you would calculate that limit.  Usually you would pick a generously large value.  It isn't really that different from figure out the space quota.  If/when you have problems you set limits, if you have tons of clients will take into account the typical number of inodes your clients actually need.  If your users need lots of inodes, you might choose a filesystem, or filesystem parameters to make more.

Comment: Zoredache, that was what I was asking. So I believe there isn't any rule of thumb here.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can limit inodes (hard and soft ),  you can limit it editing system config:

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-disk-quotas.html

Comment: That wasn't what I was asking. See Zoredache's comment, which answers my question. But thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Sorry, Not understand your question :( ( very bad english I try to improve :( )

But now I can say you, you can give 100k or 200k of inodes, but 75K is also ok, I see that on  some host providers, you need think than a single web site dont need a lot of inodes, but some cache systems for wordpress, drupal etc make alot of files ( hostgator do 150k )

And one more time sorry for dont understand you :)